# Flutter Use the RSA encrypt package

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use this dart package to create my RSA keys but the documentation is not very provided ...

[Dart package RSA_encrypt link](https://pub.dev/packages/rsa_encrypt)

In the documentation they say to use "encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1" but it is not recognized, did you manage to use it?

```
import 'package:rsa_encrypt/rsa_encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart' as crypto;

//Future to hold our KeyPair
    Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair> futureKeyPair;
    //to store the KeyPair once we get data from our future
    crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair;
    Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>> getKeyPair()
    {
      var helper = RsaKeyHelper();
      return helper.computeRSAKeyPair(helper.getSecureRandom());
    }

    futureKeyPair = getKeyPair();
    keyPair = await futureKeyPair;
    print(keyPair);

    var public = encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1(keyPair.publicKey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1` is under `RsaKeyHelper()` class.

it should be like:

```
var helper = RsaKeyHelper();
var public = helper.encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1(keyPair.publicKey);
```

Comment: when doing `helper.encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1(keyPair.publicKey);` i get `The argument type 'PublicKey' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RSAPublicKey'`. Any idea why?